# The type of the expression must be an array type but it is resolved to ArrayList<Point2D.Double>

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to figure out the proper way to call arrays from the area method, which are then supposed to calculate the area of the points given. Not sure what the proper way to select the specific x and y coordinates from each array is.

MyPolygon class

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double;

/**
 * A class that represents a geometric polygon. Methods are provided for adding
 * a point to the polygon and for calculating the perimeter and area of the
 * polygon.
 */
class MyPolygon {

    // list of the points of the polygon
    private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points;

    /**
     * Constructs a polygon with no points in it.
     */
    public MyPolygon() {
        points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a point to the end of the list of points in the polygon.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            The x coordinate of the point.
     * @param y
     *            The y coordinate of the point.
     */
    public void add(double x, double y) {
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * Calculates and returns the perimeter of the polygon.
     * 
     * @return 0.0 if < 2 points in polygon, otherwise returns the sum of the
     *         lengths of the line segments.
     */
    public double perimeter() {

        if (points.size() < 2) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        int i = 0;
        double d = 0;
        double total = points.get(0).distance(points.get(points.size() - 1));

        while (i < points.size() - 1) {
            Point2D.Double point1 = points.get(i);
            // double x = point1.x;
            // double y = point1.y;
            Point2D.Double point2 = points.get(i + 1);
            // double x1 = point2.x;
            // double y1 = point2.y;

            d = point1.distance(point2);
            // d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x,2) + Math.pow(y1 - y, 2));

            total = total + d;
            i++;

        }
        return total;

    }

    /**
     * Calculates and returns the area of the polygon.
     * 
     * @return 0.0 if < 3 points in the polygon, otherwise returns the area of
     *         the polygon.
     */
    public double area() {

        int i = 0;
        double a = 0;
        double total = 0;
        total = total + a;

        if (points.size() < 3) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        for (int m = 0; m < points.size(); m++) {

            total = total + (points[m].x() * points[m + 1].y()) - (points[m].y() * points[m + 1].x());
        }
        return 0.5 * total;
    }

}
```

Tester Class

```
class PolygonTester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyPolygon poly = new MyPolygon();
        poly.add(1.0,1.0);
        poly.add(3.0,1.0);
        poly.add(1.0,3.0);
        System.out.println(poly.perimeter());
        System.out.println(poly.area());
    }

}
```

Comment: To be specific its in the for loop that the issue is coming up. the total = total + (issue)

Answer (score 1):

Your headline is actually already the solution. You use `points[m]` which is array notation. But `points` ist not an array. It is a list. Use `points.get(int i)` instead, as you did in `perimeter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run out of bounds on the list. Your for loop continues while m < size(). However you access m+1 in your calculation. So if the list contains 5 elements and m = 4, (4 < 5) so keep looping, you will then access m + 1 which is 5. You don't have an index of 5 since these lists are 0 based.

Also the code is probably not compiling because you're using array syntax to access a list. You should say `points.get(m)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple, and is given away by your title (which I assume to be a compiler error.)

You are treating `points` as an array, which it is not. You access elements of an `ArrayList` slightly differently: you use `points.get(m)` instead of `points[m]`. If you make that change in `area`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayLists are not arrays. They are objects that are indexed with the `get(int)` method.
Wherever you have `points[m]`, or something similar, replace it with `points.get(m)`. The line would then become:

```
total = total + (points.get(m).x() * points.get(m + 1).y()) - (points.get(m).y() * points.get(m + 1).x());
```

That should clear up that issue, but you will still probably get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the last iteration of the loop, because you will be trying to index m + 1 when m is the last index. You should change your code depending on how you want it to handle the last element.